# How to cut ellipse?

Tags: ios, cashapelayer

I am drawing jigsaw using CAShapeLayer.Drawing a line that is easy part and also i did it.But now i want to draw ellipse with cutting some portion of that ellipse.Now my question is how can i cut ellipse using CGPathAddEllipseInRect?Here is my code :

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [shapeLayer setBounds:self.bounds];
    [shapeLayer setPosition:self.center];
    [shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [shapeLayer setLineWidth:3.0f];

    // Setup the path
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 10, 10);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 75,10);
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(75, 10, 50, 20));
    [shapeLayer setPath:path];
    CGPathRelease(path);

    [[self layer] addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Hint will be appreciated.

Comment: So you want an ellipse with a segment missing, but should it really be part of the line (a single line to make the full border)?

Comment: yes exactly.some part of ellipse should be missed.no much but some.And i dont think so it should be part of line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `CGPathAddEllipseInRect`, instead you need to calculate the start and end positions and use `CGPathAddArcToPoint` or, more likely, `CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint`.

Comment: yes i can do  but i was thinking CGPathAddEllipseInRect is better.Any way let me try first...

Comment: i tried it but it is not looking like ellipse...is there any other option?

Comment: Don't feel that you're limited to using only 1 curve, you can add multiple to get the shape you're after. You can't use `CGPathAddEllipseInRect` in the way you originally wanted to.